# Como tornar responsiva uma imagem dentro de uma caixa, utilizando CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Boa noite, estou com muita dificuldade em fazer a seguinte ideia funcionar:

Quando passo o mouse em cima de determinado ponto, aparece uma caixa com uma imagem, mas eu queria que essa imagem dentro da caixa fosse responsiva e se ajustasse conforme o tamanho da tela.

Então tentei o seguinte:

```
<div id="descricao" style="position:fixed; display:none; left:25%; top:25%; bottom:25%; right:25%;background:url(http://i66.tinypic.com/30201gn.png) center no-repeat ;opacity:9;  box-shadow:0 2px 5px #000; border-radius:5px; text-align:center;">Descrição da Imagem, apenas mais um teste!</div>
```

Consegui que a caixa sempre apareça no meio do navegador, independente do tamanho, o problema é a imagem dentro da caixa, que não está se ajustando.

Como posso ajustar a imagem dentro da caixa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta essa propriedade do css:

background-size: 100% 100%;

Abaixo segue um exemplo:

```css
.bg {
 position:fixed; 
 left:25%; 
 top:25%; 
 bottom:25%; 
 right:25%;
 background:url(http://i66.tinypic.com/30201gn.png) center no-repeat ;
 opacity:9;  
 box-shadow:0 2px 5px #000; 
 border-radius:5px; 
 text-align:center;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">Descrição da Imagem</div>
```

Acho que com essa propriedade fica melhor:

background-size: contain;

```css
.bg {
 position:fixed; 
 left:25%; 
 top:25%; 
 bottom:25%; 
 right:25%;
 background:url(http://i66.tinypic.com/30201gn.png) no-repeat center ;
 opacity:9;  
 box-shadow:0 2px 5px #000; 
 border-radius:5px; 
 text-align:center;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">Descrição da Imagem</div>
```

Comment: background-size: contain foi a solução para o meu problema, também em outra pergunta me responderam com o background-size: cover, ambos ajudaram muito. Agradeço!